# JavaFX load one of fxml file depends on window

Tags: java, javafx

I'm totally new in JavaFX... Until now, for my basic app I had all in one class - Main class. Now I want to extend my app and do this in proper way, so I would like to make controllers. As far as I know, I need to put package of my controller in root element in FXML file.
In my case it is AnchorPane element and I put something like this:

```
fx:controller="hr.controller.MainWindowController"
```

And in this controller should be all injections for ID's and methods, right? By injections I mean **@FXML** annotation. But how I connect this with my Main class? What should be in Main class? I know (I thinks so :P) that Main should extends Application class. So it contains this method:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {}
```

What's more and what I said in the beginning I also want be able to load/open new window after some action. Let's say that I have file **mainWindow.fxml** with above reference to the controller. The second file **window2.fxml** should be loaded after action on button in the 1st window.

Could you tell me, how should I achive this?

**UPDATE!**
Main class:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root =     FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("mainWindow.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

MainWindowController:

```
public class MainWindowController{

    @FXML
    private Button btnSave;

    @FXML
    private MenuBar menuBar;

    @FXML
    private MenuItem exit;

    @FXML
    public void handleAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Stage stage = null;
        Parent root = null;
        if(event.getSource()==exit){
            stage = (Stage) menuBar.getScene().getWindow();
            root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("window2.fxml"));
        } else {
            stage =(Stage) btnSave.getScene().getWindow();
            root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("mainWindow.fxml"));
        }
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Is this the proper way? It works how I want to, but I'm not sure if it should looks like this :)

Comment: Your main class should contain very little: just the `start()` method which loads the FXML file, puts the content in a scene, and puts the scene in the stage. The action for opening the second fxml file is handled by the first controller. Try to implement it like that; if you have specific problems/questions come back and either edit this question or post a new question.

Comment: I updated my post :) It works, but is this fine?